# USB 3.x to Ethernet then Ethernet back to USB 3.x IC a.k.a usb over ip

Tags: usb, integrated-circuit, ethernet, usb-hub, optical-fibre

Hey all I’ve been looking around a lot for a company that has a type of USB 3.x over IP. The ones I only see are not ICs but full blown products. These products cost $250+ so I’m looking to see if I could crate one myself for much less.

There are many USB 2.0 to Ethernet then Ethernet back to USB 2.0. Mostly known as a USB 2.0 over IP. Unlike the USB 3.0 variant, these USB 2.0’s are quite cheap. Some can be had for even under $20. I’m able to find ICs for those just fine but still nothing for the 3.0.

The IC I have found for USB 2.0 over IP:

[Elite](https://www.display-solution.com/en/usb-lcd-display-chips-ics-socs/usb-over-ethernet-network-soc-elite-silicon/) **USB-OVER-GIGABIT
ETHERNET CHIP**

The product I found that’s USB 3.x over ip is this one:

[Digi](https://www.digi.com/products/models/aw02-g300) **The dual USB 3.1 Gen 1 Ports, single 10M/100M/1G Ethernet**.

I’m beginning to think that all of these USB 3.0 over IP products are proprietary to that company and only they can produce it. AKA closed source/distribution. Even DigiKey can not find any chips for doing this.

The reason behind this is that I am needing at least 45ft from my server room to my office. I’m already running hdmi over fiber from there to my office and I installed a 35ft active USB 3.0 in wall when building the office. Once completed I hooked everything up and it was just too long of a distance because it would go off and on constantly. This even happened when I placed both power injectors on both ends.

There are also USB 3.x over fiber but I’m sure I could not build one of those since it deals with fiber optic converting and everything else that goes along with creating that. These also flux a lot in from from $150+.

[Spetra](http://www.icron.com/products/icron-brand/usb-extenders/fiber/usb-3-0-spectra-3022/) **2 Port USB 3.0 Multimode Fiber Extender**

It would be great if anyone knew of an IC that can do 3.x over IP.

Comment: Do you actually need USB over IP (sharing media with an IP network, and routable)? Or do you actually just need USB over Cat6, point to point? Because that's a completely different proposition.

Comment: You must value your time at next to nothing if you're considering building your own devices here instead of spending $250. You're looking at a few weeks of full-time work - and that's if it all works on the 1st spin...

Comment: You can do that with usbip on any linux box like a Pi. https://developer.ridgerun.com/wiki/index.php?title=How_to_setup_and_use_USB/IP

Comment: @bobflux Although a really great idea that i never even thought of there is the drawback of not being a true 5Gbit/sec or 10Gbit/sec USB 3.x speed.

Comment: It'll be limited by ethernet anyway, and it will probably be slow because ping time, but you should try between two PCs... costs nothing.